# Remove a UIButton programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am having the code below to create the button.

```
UIButton *but= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                [but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [but setFrame:CGRectMake(655, 320, 35, 35)];
                but.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
                [but setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [but setExclusiveTouch:YES];
                [self.view addSubview:but];
```

and used this code to recognise the touch.

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{

    [self text2];

}
```

My problem is how can I hide or remove this button that i created if i pressed on this button?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More explanations to hidden the button, button come to your method as a sender, hidden this:

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self text2];
    sender.hidden = YES;
}
```

To remove, you need its Reference Counting will be 0, remove from superview and put to nil, the NSLog it's to see than it doesn't exist.

```
  -(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
        [sender removeFromSuperview];
         sender = nil;
         NSLog(@"View sender %@",[sender description]);
}
```

Comment: Would be good to add a description, also this only hides the button what about the other half of the question? Removing it.

Comment: @Popeye here you are. Best

Answer (score 1):

You need to either store a reference to the button in your view controller, in a way similar to how it is done with buttons added through UI Builder, or tag the button, and use `viewWithTag` to retrieve it.

The second approach is probably easier to implement:

```
UIButton *but= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
but.tag = 123;
... // The rest of your code
```

when you need to remove it, use

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:123] setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[button removeFromSuperview];`